# object passed to method by reference not maintaining values from DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Basically, I'm passing a model object to a method and in that method, assigning the proper object from the database. Since this is a reference, I assumed it would persist throughout the rest of the method in which it it was called/passed. I know this has something to do with the proxy of entity framework but can't figure out how to fix it. Here is a fragment of the code:

```
    [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(NewFormViewModel nfvm)
{
    db = new dbconnection(connStr);
    Track track= new Track();
    Track parentTrack = new Track();
      this.Create_SetTrack(nfvm, track, parentTrack);
         ...
```

and then in Create_SetTrack:

```
        private void Create_SetTrack(NewFormViewModel nfvm, Track track, Track parentTrack)
        {
            track = db.Tracks.FirstOrDefault();
            parentTrack = db.Tracks.Where(i=>i.ParentID==track.ID).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

The track loads in Create_SetTrack but then, after the code after the '...' continues in Create, track is back to it's null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a method parameter is a new variable. So you assign `track` (the variable) to `track` (the parameter). In the method body, the *parameter* is overwritten by a new reference, but the original `track` (the variable) has nothing to do with that.

You are probably confused by the fact that changes you make to the *same* reference object will be visible outside the method body. If you'd only set a property of a `new Track()` object, you'd see this value after the `Create_SetTrack` call.

So I would make a method that returns the tracks, so you can assign then to the original variables. If this is an internal method, you could return a `Tuple` (using `Tuple`s in API methods is discouraged, because the `ItemX` properties are too nondescript).

As an alternative, you could assign the tracks to another object (the view model?) that is not overwritten in the method body.

I'd prefer the first alternative though. I don't like methods that create side-effects.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first part of your post. See, if I fill out the properties of track by hand for example track.ID=12, track.Name="trackname" and etc, then those values persist after the Create method goes on. It's only with the DBContext that this happens. So am I not understanding this properly, are you saying that when I pass track, it's not passed by reference?

Comment: If you do `track.ID = 12` within the method, you're assigning this value to a property of the original object. But in your current code, you're overwriting the whole object, but this object is not returned from the method. It's not related to DbContext. If you'd just create a new object in the method body, the behavior would be the same.

Comment: Ok thanks. But if by that, you mean track = new Track(); in Create_SetTrack then unfortunately that didn't do the trick either. At this point I'm more interested in the why, because I did what you suggested (the method returns 2 tracks) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work unless you use a `ref` parameter. Otherwise, the `track` parameter reference will only exist in the scope of the method

```
    private void Create_SetTrack(NewFormViewModel nfvm, ref Track track)
    {
        track = db.Tracks.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

**I would advise against this, though**, since it makes the code more complicated that it needs to be. A better solution is to simply return a value from the method and assign that to your variable:

```
private Track Create_SetTrack(NewFormViewModel nfvm)
{
    return db.Tracks.FirstOrDefault();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(NewFormViewModel nfvm)
{
    db = new dbconnection(connStr);
    Track track= Create_SetTrack(nfvm);
    ....
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't type enough of what I need to do. If you look at my code now, the problem is that 2 values have to be assigned, and I can't use ref because the ref can't be used as lambda values. I'm also interested in the reason as to why this doesn't persist after leaving the method. the dbcontext has not closed yet and I can't figure out why this is the reason.

Comment: You could encapsulate both values into a single object and return that.